# current azure storage doesn't allow create new VM

Tags: powershell, azure

I have the script, which create vitrual machine, and install google chrome via dsc. I created current storage account, and executed script. But in next time I have error. This is my script:

```
    $SubscriptionName = "subscription_name"
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

    #Replace the variable values as needed
    $VMName = "CSETest"
    $StorageAccount = 'googleChrome'
    $StorageKey = 'key'
    $StorageContainer = 'dscarchives'

    $ServiceName="ChromeInstaller"

    #Get the OS image reference
    $arrayWindows=( Get-AzureVMImage | where-object { $_.ImageName -like "*Windows*Server*2012*R2*en.us*" } )

    $locationAllow=$arrayWindows[$arrayWindows.Count-1].Location
    $locationAllow=$locationAllow.Split(";")
    $locationAllow=$locationAllow  | where-object { $_ -like "* US*"}
    $Localization=(Get-Random -InputObject $locationAllow)

    #Create VM Config with last windows update
    $vmConfig = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $VMName -ImageName $arrayWindows[$arrayWindows.Count-1].ImageName -InstanceSize Small

    #Create Provisioning Configuration
    $vmProvisioningConfig = Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -VM $vmConfig -Windows -AdminUsername "login" -Password "password"

    $StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccount  -StorageAccountKey $StorageKey
    Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration -ConfigurationPath .\ChromeInstaller.ps1 -ContainerName $StorageContainer -StorageContext $StorageContext -Force

    #Set the Azure VM DSC Extension to run the LCM meta-configuration
    $vmAzureExtension = Set-AzureVMDscExtension -VM $vmProvisioningConfig -ConfigurationArchive ChromeInstaller.ps1.zip -ConfigurationName OpenChrome -Verbose -StorageContext $StorageContext -ContainerName $StorageContainer -Force

    #Create a VM
    New-AzureVM -ServiceName $ServiceName -VMs $vmAzureExtension  -Location $Localization -WaitForBoot
```

In the last line, script throw exception:

> New-AzureVM : BadRequest: The location or affinity group Central US of the storage account where the source image 
>   a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201410.01-en.us-127GB.vhd resides is not in the same location or affinity group as 
>   the specified cloud service. The source image must reside in a storage account that has the same affinity group or location as the cloud 
>   service West US.

So, as you can see, my script generate random location. And I can't link with on location. So, how can I fix this bug?

Comment: The error tells you what you need to know. If you're deploying image-based VMs in randomised US Azure locations you'll need the VHD in a local storage account in each location.

Answer (score 1):

The source image VHD must exist in the same location as the new virtual machine.  Use [AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) to copy the image to storage accounts in all locations listed in `$locationAllow`.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple answer is to create your VM in the same location as your storage account. This is telling you that your Azure OS Image in the storage account location does not exist in your cloud service location.

You can also try this

```
$AzureLocation = (get-azurelocation)
$Localization=(Get-Random -InputObject $AzureLocation)
$WindowsImage=( Get-AzureVMImage | where-object { $_.ImageName -like "*Windows*Server*2012*R2*en.us*" -and $_.Location -Match $Localization.DisplayName } | sort PublishedDate | select -first 1 ).ImageName

#Create VM Config with last windows update
$vmConfig = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $VMName -ImageName $WindowsImage -InstanceSize Small
```

With this method, we are selecting a location, then an image that resides within that location. Previously you were selecting an image (which may reside in Location West US) then selecting a location .

Alternativly, get the location of your storage account and use that location to get the image and create the cloud service in the same location of the storage account